# $_POST['formname'] issue

Tags: php, jquery, forms, post, html-select

I have a small issue with $_POST.
I have  a Select with multiple options. In each option I have a value and another attribute, data, data I use to get 2 values out of the select.

```
<select id="theId" name="theName" onchange="changeSelect();">
    <option name="0" value="0.00" data="0.00"<?php if($val==0.00)echo 'selected=""';?>>0</option>
    <option name="1" value="10" data="15" <?php if($val==10)echo 'selected=""';?>>1</option>
    <option name="2" value="15" data="20" <?php if($val==15)echo 'selected=""';?>>2</option>
    <option name="3" value="20" data="30" <?php if($val==20)echo 'selected=""';?>>3</option>
</select>
```

I then use the following code to get the values:

```
var val1 = parseFloat($("select#theId option:selected").attr('value'));
var val2 = parseFloat($("select#theId option:selected").attr('data-us'));
```

Everything works perfectly... except when I try to store the values in the database... I can only use

```
$data = array(
        'val1' => $_POST['theName'],
        'val2' => $_POST['theName']
    );
```

as far as I know, since $_POST is using the form name ($_POST['formname']).
If I use the above code, it will store the value of val1 for both val1 AND val2.

Is there any other way I could store these values?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, but try with [] in your attribute name (like `<input name="foo[]" /> <input name="foo[]" />` the résult : `$_POST[foo][0] and $_POST[foo][1]`

Comment: Put the data into a hidden input.

Comment: @Barmar but wouldn't it still have to be in the same select? like 
`<select><option ...><input ...></input></option>...</select>`
Wouldn't it still be the same form name?

Comment: @Jocker See the ansert I posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a hidden input to the form

```
<input type="hidden" name="theNameData" id="theNameData">
```

and copy the data to the hidden input.

```
$("#theNameData").val(val2);
```

Then you can use `$_POST['theNameData']` in PHP to get this.

Comment: Thank you very much. How didn't I think of this? I'm even using this for other things in the app. :))
Your help is much appreciated.